# Can you resolve an RoR app to the public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, hosting, resolution

I've been back and forth with Network Solutions for weeks. All they have is an file upload button to upload your application to, and that's it. No way to start up the application, or SSH into the server. When I did follow their directions explicitly, and received a 403 Forbidden even though my files were 775, I emailed them, and these were my responses.

Waiting 2 days, I got this response..

`We apologize for the inconvenience. We have checked your files on the server and we have determined that there is no index file uploaded on /htdocs/rails/testingApp/public directory. Please upload your index file inside the /public directory.`

..because RoR runs out of the public directory now?

I explained to them, kindly, that RoR apps do not resolve to the public directory.

2 days later..

`I apologize for the confusion, the way our rails apps deploy, the /public/ folder will be the default directory that http://testingapp.yourwebsite.com/ resolves to. You may need to alter or redeploy if your applicaton is set to run it's public root from another folder.`

Whose dumb here? I can't tell. Is there a way to resolve an RoR app to the public folder?

Comment: Run, don't walk, away from Network Solutions. Find a real hosting provider.

Comment: Any kind of service provider that uses the phrase "We apologize for the **inconvenience** " deserves an inconvenient kick in the butt. An unfulfilled service is not an *inconvenience*. It is a deal breaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, actually the middleware (Rack I think?) that resides between the webserver and Rails takes care to convert an HTTP request that arrives on `yourname.com/` following the routes file to the correct controller and paired view.

This means that you won't never have a *real* file in public which represents the index of your page.. I don't get what they are asking about (since they explicitly state that they offer RoR hosting). Their request seems just incompetency.

The public folder is used to publish static resources but just for that so that every requests that points to a static source under root of the URL, eg `yoursite.com/static_img.jpg`, is forwarded to the real file residing in that directory, this is not true for normal RoR views.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like they are using [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) to serve Rails apps, for which the DocumentRoot is indeed the Rails /public subdirectory. This is a common hosting scenario for Rails apps.

Comment: Yeah, but why do they need an index.html file? That's a routinely removed file, so that you can use any controller action as the "home" action, no?

Comment: hmm.. how  you would then resolve the RoR app to the public dir/ ?

Comment: Passenger knows to load the application from the directory above /public. This is actually a sensible way for an Apache extension to work: this way requests for static entities go straight through to the directory, instead of incurring Rails overhead. Only requests which can't be satisfied statically are forwarded to the Rails app.

Comment: That said, requiring an index file is peculiar, since it is the removal of this file that should trigger requests to the home page to go to your app instead of a static file.

Comment: Well, do I have to add a passenger gem? Am really falling on my face as to how to deploy on networks solutions. How I long for heroku.

Answer (score 2):

I am really happy with webfaction, which offers about the same functionality, excellent rails (even rails 3) support, ssh access, and i find them really cheap.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted the Passenger Answer, but I think your real answer might lie in http://heroku.com/. quite possibly one of the easiest deployments of rails I have ever done.

Comment: Yes, I do enjoy Heroku. And I also enjoy MediaTemple, and WebFaction seems good. My all time favorite is EngineYard. And NS can suck my proverbial #$%#

Comment: I love Heroku but it can get pricey quick.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an .htaccess file? You could add a rewrite rule for index.html.